# XMPP / Ejabberd: Why does the roster item is always ask='subscribe'?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

The roster of user "john@localhost" is

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="john@localhost/2182919552157840751291" from="john@localhost" type="result" id="56c73b295y">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item subscription="both" jid="johnna@localhost"/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

But the roster of user "johnna@localhost" is

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="johnna@localhost/15960489746475669037996" from="johnna@localhost" type="result" id="56c73b295y">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item ask="subscribe" jid="john@localhost"/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

How it's possible ?
Why item is ask="subscribe" when john has both subscription ?

### Step to reproduce

*eJabberd version: `ejabberd/ecs:20.01`*

john@localhost send stanza:

```
<presence type="subscribe" to="johnna@localhost" id="test1" />
```

johnna@localhost reply with:

```
<presence type="subscribed" to="john@localhost" id="test1" />
```

Then send:

```
<presence type="subscribe" to="john@localhost" id="test2" />
```

Finally, john@localhost reply:

```
<presence type="subscribed" to="johnna@localhost" id="test2" />
```

Roster iq received by john is

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="johnna@localhost/15960489746475669037996" from="johnna@localhost" type="set" id="56c73b295y">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item subscription="both" jid="johnna@localhost"/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

But johnna received:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="johnna@localhost/15960489746475669037996" from="johnna@localhost" type="set" id="56c73b295y">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item ask="subscribe" jid="john@localhost"/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

### *modules enabled*

```
modules:
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_block_strangers: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    default: always
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_roster: {}
```

Comment: Is this a game, a riddle, a puzzle game, or a folk tale? As there is no context, it's almost impossible to solve. What ejabberd version, what client, steps to replicate the problem, make it ieasy for anybody to reproduce the problem and investigate it...

Comment: Sorry, question updated !

Comment: ... but it's not strange to have a "subscription=both" on one side and "ask=subscribe" on the other side

Comment: I've installed that 20.01 version, configured like you, logged in with Tkabber in two accounts, and using the client XML console I send the stanzas that you provided. Then I login again with both clients, and they receive the roster items correctly. Johnna has the contact with subscription=both, not ask=subscribe. So, no idea why you have that problem. You can perform the tests with any desktop client that has XML console like Tkabber, Gajim or Psi, and check what's going on.

Comment: Yes, it's very strange ! ... honestly, it was working few days ago.
I will install a fresh ejabberd and try again.
I was playing with ejabberdctl command